# What are you thinking of the class?

Tags: present-continuous

Is **What are you thinking of the class?** a natural way to ask your opinion about the class at the beginning of the course?

It's about the student's expectations,  if they're being met. Or their first impression of the course. What they think of the course so far, if they like the methodology, the content...

Comment: "What do you think of ...." is more natural.

Comment: We don't proofread here. You may want to visit [this site's help pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) for advice about how to ask a good question. (The DV isn't mine, BTW.)

Comment: I agree with @Graffito that usage is more natural in general, but I'm not sure it's appropriate here. At the beginning of the course, presumably I don't yet know what I think. Really we need to know more about what the asker is trying to learn. Is it about the students' expectations for the class, perhaps?

Comment: @Pumpkincake I see, so the question is being asked a little bit after the start of the course? The students have had some time to form an opinion, but the instructor (you?) could still change things?

Comment: @Graffito To add the idea of it being the beginning of the course to your example, how about "What do you think of the class *so far*?" OP even uses "so far" later on in the question. I think the present continuous sounds perfectly acceptable though - it's just less formal than the version with "do."